# How do I write this MySQL query to get the correct information? (Subquery, multiple subqueries)

Tags: sql, mysql

Here is the query that I am working on:

```
SELECT `unitid`, `name` FROM apartmentunits
WHERE aptid = (
    SELECT `aptid` FROM rentconditionsmap WHERE rentcondid = 1 AND condnum = 1
)
```

What I am having trouble figuring out is how to write this to add more rentcondition limiters to filter this list down more.

```
SELECT `aptid` FROM rentconditionsmap WHERE rentcondid = 1 AND condnum = 1
```

Data:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `rentconditionsmap` (
   `rcid` bigint(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
   `rentcondid` int(3) unsigned NOT NULL, 
   `condnum` tinyint(3) unsigned NOT NULL, 
   `aptid` bigint(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL, 
   PRIMARY KEY (`rcid`), KEY `aptid` (`aptid`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=18 ;

INSERT INTO `rentconditionsmap` 
  (`rcid`, `rentcondid`, `condnum`, `aptid`) 
VALUES 
  (1, 1, 1, 1), 
  (2, 2, 1, 1), 
  (3, 3, 0, 1), 
  (4, 4, 1, 1), 
  (5, 8, 0, 1);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `apartmentunits` (
  `unitid` bigint(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
  `aptid` bigint(10) NOT NULL, 
  `name` varchar(6) NOT NULL, 
  `verified` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0', 
  `rentcost` int(4) unsigned DEFAULT NULL, 
  `forrent` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0', 
  `unittypekey` varchar(2) DEFAULT NULL, 
  `sqft` smallint(6) DEFAULT NULL, 
  PRIMARY KEY (`unitid`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=121 ;

INSERT INTO `apartmentunits` 
  (`unitid`, `aptid`, `name`, `verified`, `rentcost`, `forrent`, `unittypekey`, `sqft`) 
VALUES 
  (1, 1, '3', 1, 540, 0, '2B', NULL), 
  (2, 1, '5', 1, NULL, 0, '2B', NULL), 
  (3, 1, '7', 1, NULL, 0, '2B', NULL), 
  (53, 1, '1', 1, NULL, 0, '2B', NULL), 
  (54, 1, '2', 1, NULL, 0, '2B', NULL), 
  (55, 1, '4', 1, 570, 0, '2B', NULL), 
  (56, 1, '6', 1, NULL, 0, '2B', NULL), 
  (57, 1, '8', 1, NULL, 0, '2B', NULL), 
  (58, 1, '9', 1, NULL, 0, '2B', NULL), 
  (59, 1, '10', 1, NULL, 0, '2B', NULL), 
  (60, 1, '11', 1, NULL, 0, '2B', NULL);
```

Comment: Your subquery will always return the literal value 'aptid' for all records that satisfy your WHERE clause. Is that what you want?

Comment: @flayto - no it won't. backtick is the identifier quote char in mysql.

Comment: @Ben: Thank you for the data and table definitions!  But your tables are MyISAM - won't enforce referencial integrity :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Eric J said as a comment:

> Try changing = to IN

```
SELECT `unitid`, `name` FROM apartmentunits
WHERE `aptid` IN (
    SELECT `aptid` FROM rentconditionsmap WHERE rentcondid = 1 AND condnum = 1
)
```

Comment: Still, that only deals with limiting by one set of rentconditions. I need to be able to query more than one set to limit the apartmentunits returned.

Comment: Sure, but it's _an_ answer, which is why i added it. If you need more, just add OR clauses to the WHERE. `WHERE aptid IN (..) OR aptid IN (..)`

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. Tested and that seems to work:

SELECT `unitid`, `name` FROM apartmentunits WHERE aptid IN (SELECT `aptid` FROM rentconditionsmap WHERE rentcondid = 4 AND condnum = 1) AND aptid IN (SELECT `aptid` FROM rentconditionsmap WHERE rentcondid = 2 AND condnum = 1) ORDER BY name ASC

Answer (score 1):

why not:

`SELECT unitid, name

FROM apartmentunits a
INNER JOIN rentconditionsmap r on a.aptid = r.aptid

WHERE (rentcondid = 1 and condnum = 1) OR (rentcondid = 2 and condnum = 2)`

Comment: SELECT a.unitid, a.name FROM apartmentunits a INNER JOIN rentconditionsmap r ON a.aptid = r.aptid WHERE (r.rentcondid = 1 AND r.condnum = 1) AND (r.rentcondid = 2 AND r.condnum = 1)

Tested, and returns no results, where I can see there should be one aptid that matches that set of rentconditions.

Answer (score 1):

Using ANSI-92 join syntax:

```
SELECT au.unitid, 
       au.name 
  FROM APARTMENTUNITS au
  JOIN RENTCONDITIONSMAP rcm ON rcm.aptid = au.aptid
                            AND rcm.rentcondid = 1
                            AND rcm.condnum = 1
```

Comment: ANSI-92 syntax is much more readable. The WHERE clause should only have conditions that apply after the JOIN. 1 up

Answer (score 0):

Use a JOIN (below is TSQL sintax for a join, or you can use the explicit INNER JOIN).

```
SELECT apartmentunits.unitid, apartmentunits.name 
FROM apartmentunits, rentconditionsmap
WHERE apartmentunits.aptid = rentconditionsmap.aptid
AND rentconditionsmap.rentcondid = 1
AND rentconditionsmap.condnum = 1
-- AND whatever else...
```